# Daphne server unable to handle http requests

Tags: django, python-3.x, daphne, python-socketio

I have a django application that I want to deploy using daphne.

Django application supports both **websockets** and **http** requests. I've converted the django to support ASGI.

I'm starting the server using :

```
daphne <project_name>.asgi:application
```

The server is able to accept *websocket* connections but unable to handle the incoming *HTTP* requests (**throws 404**).

Where am I going wrong over here?

P.S.: I'm not using django channels.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to instantiate 'get_asgi_application' while creating the django application. Hence, it wasn't able to accept HTTP requests.